# Matlab csvread() creating wrong matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix

I simply want to import a matrix from a .csv into Matlab and find that Matlab is acting differently wrt length of a row in my csv. :

First, I read a file of 2 rows with 50000 columns and Matlab correctly shows a 2*50000 matrix in my workspace.
Now, if the file consists of 2 rows with 100000 columns, Matlab identifies it as a 200000*1 matrix.

What has gone wrong there?

Comment: Do the files have the exact same length? How are you calling `csvread`? there is no enough information to diagnose.

Comment: Are you sure the second file has the correct line break token at the end of the first line (i.e. is it definitely identical to the first file?)

Comment: no, the files are of different length: same number of rows, 2, but doubling the number of columns from 50000 to 100000 results in above behavior. My function call: m = csvread('testOutputBig_Rho.csv');

Comment: @Dan, Yes it does. The files are created in the same manner. Opening the csv in excel shows, that they have the desired shape: 2 by number of columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What command are you using? `csvread('filename.csv')` ?

I would personally prefer to use

`Data = importdata( 'filename.csv','\t');`

Comment: Thanks, that did the job!

Comment: Good to hear that. Good luck!